# Web Scrape Fantasy Cruncher for Historic Daily Fantasy Results

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I’m currently working on a project where we estimate the expected daily fantasy points for each NBA player and then build an optimized lineup which can plugged into various daily fantasy basketball tournaments.

In order to report metrics on our results for an entire season, we are trying to get historic fantasy tournament results (how many points did it take get first place, how many points did it take to win the minimum reward money, etc.). I’m trying to pull data from this table Fantasy Cruncher's website: https://www.fantasycruncher.com/contest-links/NBA/2021-03-10. However, the table is not included in the html source code. Anyone have advice on how I could scrape data from that website?

We are using Python 3 for this project, and so far have tried BeautifulSoup, Pandas, and couple other libraries that were mentioned in posts I found online.

Note: I'm open to suggestions on alternative websites to find this data, however it's not something that's widely available. Even Fanduel's website has a similar set up where the data you see on the page does not show up in the html source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this example how to load the data from the page:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = (
    "https://www.fantasycruncher.com/funcs/tournament-analyzer/get-contests.php"
)

data = {
    "sites[]": [
        "draftkings",
        "draftkings_pickem",
        "draftkings_showdown",
        "fanduel",
        "fanduel_single",
        "fanduel_super",
        "fantasydraft",
        "yahoo",
        "superdraft",
    ],
    "leagues[]": "NBA",
    "periods[]": "2021-03-10",
}

data = requests.post(url, data=data).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
            id                 site league  slate          site_id                                               name      period  max_entries  max_entrants      cost  prizepool  places_paid  total_entrants  winning_score  mincash_score   startdate  winning_payout  mincash_payout             DateTime                     Title  game_cnt  winner_cnt                                             winner  has_lineups
0    675539213              fanduel    NBA  55339  55339-244619717     $25K Tue NBA Piggy Bank Shot (150 Entries Max)  2021-03-10          150        598802      0.05      25000       180000          392082         366.20         279.50  1615424400         1000.00            0.10  2021-03-10 20:00:00                      Main         2           0                                  hornethurricane25            1
1    675539237              fanduel    NBA  55339  55339-244619991           $1M Tue NBA Comeback Shot ($200K to 1st)  2021-03-10          150        297619      4.00    1000000        78971          250535         366.20         284.80  1615424400       200000.00            7.00  2021-03-10 20:00:00                      Main         2           0                                      calieternal85            1
2    675539211              fanduel    NBA  55339  55339-244619739  $25K Tue NBA Fadeaway ($0.25 to Enter, 20 Entr...  2021-03-10           20        119760      0.25      25000        35937           80362         359.00         275.10  1615424400          500.00            0.50  2021-03-10 20:00:00                      Main         2           0                              ketchdenny,bbgj278990            1
3    675532537           draftkings    NBA  46045        104452190           NBA $1M Return From Break [$250K to 1st]  2021-03-10          150        117647     10.00    1000000        24790           98331         330.50         261.75  1615424400       250000.00           15.00  2021-03-10 20:00:00                 Late Swap         2           2                             blankco216,markvikings            1
4    678166877       fanduel_single    NBA  55354  55354-244682782      $3K Wed NBA Piggy Bank Shot (150 Entries Max)  2021-03-10          150         71856      0.05       3000        21550           37734         285.76         231.50  1615426200          100.00            0.10  2021-03-10 20:30:00                  SA @ DAL         1           0  bearcats594,cloverbandit,ceegee,richdeese,drs1...            0
5    675532493           draftkings    NBA  46045        104452184                    NBA $50K And-One [20 Entry Max]  2021-03-10           20         59453      1.00      50000        15950           59453         330.75         259.75  1615424400         2500.00            1.50  2021-03-10 20:00:00                 Late Swap         2           1                                           Bradsh86            1
6    678166786       fanduel_single    NBA  55353  55353-244682520      $2K Wed NBA Piggy Bank Shot (150 Entries Max)  2021-03-10          150         47904      0.05       2000        14375           32370         308.42         255.85  1615424400          100.00            0.10  2021-03-10 20:00:00                 WAS @ MEM         1           0         joseph36,fadeaway2324,splashvinnie,jdarich            0
7    675532511           draftkings    NBA  46045        104450982                  NBA $20K mini-MAX [150 Max Entry]  2021-03-10          150         47562      0.50      20000         9972           47562         328.75         264.75  1615424400         2000.00            1.00  2021-03-10 20:00:00                 Late Swap         2           1                                             TashaB            1

...
```

and creates `data.csv` (Screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Ive been wondering this same thing for a while. How did you get to that link? I am hopeful to do the same thing to download the player lists each day but cant find the URL to it

Comment: @On_an_island thanks for your response. I havent been back to stackoverflow in a while but this helps and I will play with this sometime this week!